# Make KnexJS Transactions work with async/await

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, knex.js

I'm trying to make transactions work with async/await and knexjs but to no avail.

The code (snippet is for the sake of shortening the post):

```js
const updateOrder = (req, res, db, logger) => {
  let {
    status,
    trx_id,
    orNumber,
    returnReason
  } = req.body;

  const updateStatus = () => {
    return db('cart')
      .returning('*')
      .where('trx_id', '=', trx_id)
      .update({
        status: status,
        or_num: orNumber,
        return_reason: returnReason
      });
  }

  const updateDate = () => {
    return db('cart')
      .returning('*')
      .where('trx_id', '=', trx_id)
      .update({
        date_purchased: new Date()
      });
  }

  const selectItems = (order) => {
    return db
      .select('*')
      .from('cart_items')
      .where({
        cart_id: order.id,
        trx_id: order.trx_id
      });
  }

  const selectProduct = (item) => {
    const queries = [];
    item.forEach(item => {
      const query = db.select('*')
        .from('product')
        .where('item_code', '=', item.item_code);
      queries.push(query);
    })
    return Promise.all(queries);
  }

  const updateQuantity = (product, cart) => {
    const prodQuantity = product.map(product => parseInt(product.stock));
    const cartQuantity = cart.map(cart => parseInt(cart.quantity));
    const newQuantity = [];
    const queries = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
      newQuantity.push(prodQuantity[i] - cartQuantity[i]);
    }
    cart.map((cart, index) => {
      const query = db('products')
        .returning('*')
        .where('item_code', '=', cart.item_code)
        .update({
          stock: newQuantity[index]
        })
      queries.push(query);
    })
    return queries;
  }

  const updateLogs = () => {
    return db('activity_order_logs')
      .returning('*')
      .insert({
        date: new Date(),
        employee_id: req.session.emp_id,
        module: "MONITORING",
        trx_id: trx_id,
        activity: status,
        or_num: orNumber
      })
  }

  const sendResponse = (result) => {
    if (result) {
      res.json({
        isSuccess: true
      });
      return;
    } else {
      res.json({
        isSuccess: false
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  (async() => {
    const first = await updateStatus();

    if (first[0].status == 'Success') {
      const second = await updateDate().catch(err => {
        throw err
      });

      const third = await selectItems(second[0]).catch(err => {
        throw err
      });

      const fourth = await selectProduct(third).catch(err => {
        throw err
      });
      const fourth2 = [].concat(...fourth);

      const fifth = await updateQuantity(fourth2, third)
      const decreaseStock = async() => {
        const finalResult = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < fifth.length; i++) {
          const finalQuery = await Promise.resolve(fifth[i]);
          finalResult.push(finalQuery);
        }
        return finalResult;
      };

      const result = await decreaseStock().catch(err => {
        throw err
      });
      const result2 = [].concat(...result);
      const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
        throw err
      });
      const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);

    } else if (first[0].status == 'Returned') {
      const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
        throw err
      });
      const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
    } else {
      const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
        throw err
      });
      const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
    }
  })().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({
      isSuccess: false
    })
  });
}

module.exports = {
  updateOrder
}
```

What I've tried:

**First Try** - Error, returns *Transaction rejected with non-error*

```js
//knex is initialized as db
const createTransaction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    return db.transaction(resolve);
  });
};

(async() => {
  const trx = await createTransaction();
  const first = await updateStatus();

  if (first[0].status == 'Success') {
    const second = await updateDate().catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
 
    const third = await selectItems(second[0]).catch(err => {
      throw err
    });

    const fourth = await selectProduct(third).catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
    const fourth2 = [].concat(...fourth);

    const fifth = await updateQuantity(fourth2, third)
    const decreaseStock = async() => {
      const finalResult = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < fifth.length; i++) {
        const finalQuery = await Promise.resolve(fifth[i]);
        finalResult.push(finalQuery);
      }
      return finalResult;
    };

    const result = await decreaseStock().catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
    const result2 = [].concat(...result);
    const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
    const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);

  } else if (first[0].status == 'Returned') {
    const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
    const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
  } else {
    const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
      throw err
    });
    const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
  }

  trx.commit();

})().catch(err => {
  trx.rollback();
  console.log(err);
  res.json({
    isSuccess: false
  })
});
```

**Second Try** - Result: Transaction still commits and did not rolled back even though there's an intentional error.

```js
//knex is initalized as db
(async() => {
  try {
    return await db.transaction(async trx => {
      const first = await updateStatus();

      if (first[0].status == 'Success') {
        const second = await updateDate().catch(err => {
          throw err
        });

        const third = await selectItems(second[0]).catch(err => {
          throw err
        });

        const fourth = await selectProduct(third).catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
        const fourth2 = [].concat(...fourth);

        const fifth = await updateQuantity(fourth2, third)
        const decreaseStock = async() => {
          const finalResult = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < fifth.length; i++) {
            const finalQuery = await Promise.resolve(fifth[i]);
            finalResult.push(finalQuery);
          }
          return finalResult;
        };

        const result = await decreaseStock().catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
        const result2 = [].concat(...result);
        const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
        const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);

      } else if (first[0].status == 'Returned') {
        const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
        const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
      } else {
        const logs = await updateLogs().catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
        const sendRes = await sendResponse(logs);
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({
      isSuccess: false
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are creating transaction, but then you are not sending any queries to it, but send queries to the other database connections in knex's connection pool.

This is how you should use transactions with knex:

```
async () {
  try {
    const trxResult = await db.transaction(async (trx) => {
      const queryResult = await trx('table').where(... etc. ...);
      // do some more queries to trx
    });
    console.log("transaction was committed");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("transaction was rolled back");
  }
}
```

Also you should try reduce amount of code to minimum before posting problems to stackoverflow. Hiding too much code to snippets doesn't help at all.

Comment: this work when everything else failed. I did everything except sending queries to trx. I keep sending on db. Thank you.