# How to prevent Knex from hanging on insert

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am using Knex.js to insert values from an array into a PostgreSQL database. The problem I keep running into is that Knex will hang after inserting rows in the database.

I've been struggling with this for several hours, and have tried a variety of solutions, including [Get Knex.js transactions working with ES7 async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580674/get-knex-js-transactions-working-with-es7-async-await/40580883), [Make KnexJS Transactions work with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088660/make-knexjs-transactions-work-with-async-await), and [Knex Transaction with Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957032/knex-transaction-with-promises).

No matter which flavor I try, I come back to the hang. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, but it's possible I haven't had enough coffee.

Here's my test code:

```
const testArray = [
  {line: 'Canterbury Tales'},
  {line: 'Moby Dick'},
  {line: 'Hamlet'}
];

const insertData = (dataArray) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    const data = dataArray.map(x => {
      return {
          file_line: x.line
      };
    });

    let insertedRows;

    db.insert(data)
      .into('file_import')  
      .then((result) => {
        insertedRows = result.rowCount;
        resolve(insertedRows);
      })
  });
}

const testCall = (b) => {
  insertData(b).then((result) => {
    console.log(`${result} rows inserted.`);
  })
}

testCall(testArray);
```

This returns the following:

```
3 rows inserted.
```

**EDIT: Updating with solution**
Thanks to @sigmus, I was able to get this working by adding `db.destroy()`. Here's the updated code block, fully functional:

```
const testArray = [
  {line: 'Canterbury Tales'},
  {line: 'Moby Dick'},
  {line: 'Hamlet'}
];

const insertData = (dataArray) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    const data = dataArray.map(x => {
      return {
          file_line: x.line
      };
    });

    let insertedRows;

    db.insert(data)
      .into('file_import')  
      .then((result) => {
        insertedRows = result.rowCount;
        resolve(insertedRows);
      })
      .finally(() => {              
        db.destroy();
      });
  });
}

const testCall = (b) => {
  insertData(b).then((result) => {
    console.log(`${result} rows inserted.`);
    process.exit(0);
  })
}

testCall(testArray);
```

Comment: Would it help if you add a ```process.exit(0);``` right after ```console.log(`${result} rows inserted.`);```?

Comment: @sigmus That does allow the app to end, thank you! However, I wonder if there's still a better way? I tried `process.exitCode = 0` to exit naturally per https://stackoverflow.com/a/37592669/1575022, but the app still hangs. So, `process.exit(0)` feels like a stopgap.

Comment: Without process.exit, does it take a long time to exit or it never exits at all? Maybe it's a connection pool issue, try using ```destroy``` like explained here: https://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling

Comment: @sigmus, genius! I didn't even think to check that. If you re-post as the answer, I'll accept and update original post with solution. Thank you!

Comment: Re-posted as an answer, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `process.exit(0);` right after `` console.log(`${result} rows inserted.`); `` the script should exit.

It may be the case it's a connection pool issue, try using `destroy` like explained here: https://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I updated my question with your solution.